# Show Spinning Animation while Page Loads ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know that in my web application, the user clicks to the menu, It's buffering sometimes to load the page.

So the Theme I used to create the system has inbuild animation for that. How I can trigger this when loading until the page completely loads to view.

This is the animation

```
 <div id="loading" class="overlay"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i></div>
```

This is currently how I placed it on the page.

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <h3 class="card-title">
      <b>Company List</b>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="loading" class="overlay">
    <i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
  <!-- /.card-header -->
  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th> Company Name </th>
        <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status) </th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tbody> @foreach (var item in Model) { <tr>
          <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompanyName) </td>
          <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status) </td>
          <td> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning pull-right" }) @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success pull-right" }) @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger pull-right" }) </td>
        </tr> } </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.card-body -->
</div>
```

I Used this JQuery

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: @Bravo I have used this Jquery code. But even the page is loaded, Animation is still there.

Comment: `$('#loading')` ... you have no element with `id="loading"` - try `<div class="overlay" id="loading">`

Comment: @Bravo ``<div id="loading" class="overlay"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-sync-alt fa-spin"></i></div>``

Comment: erm in the code where you say `This is currently how I placed it on the page.` - there is no `id="loading"` so, what's the next move?

Comment: @Bravo Sorry My bad. I have edited the code again.

Comment: so after you fixed that, it's still not hiding? perhaps try `$(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load()` has been removed in jQuery 3.0. Try using:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('#loading').hide();
});
```